# How to configure docker daemon.json to always mount specific path?

Tags: docker, docker-daemon

I want to mount host's specific path always when container started.

Is it possible to configure `daemon.json` to do this rather than specify `-v` option from `docker run` command?

Comment: I don't think daemon.json has such an option. If you're tired of putting various args (`-v`, `-p`, etc) when you run your container, maybe look into `docker-compose` so you can have all those args codified into yaml.

Comment: If your use case of Docker is to run a `gitlab-ci` pipeline, you might want to have a look at [this section Gitlab's documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#the-persistent-storage).